# How to resolve probabilities over natural numbers?

Tags: equation-solving, probability-or-statistics

Given a simple function `f`:

```
f[n_, b_] := Mod[n, b]
```

How to compute the probability of `f[n_, b_] == 0` for arbitrary $n\in ℕ^+$? I.e., the probability of `f[n, b] == 0` is $1/b$ for $n \in ℕ^+$.

Indeed, this function is trivial but I am looking for general ways to solve this kind of problems. I am not sure if [*Probability*](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Probability.html) is suited for this.

Comment: Not only does the function `Probability` require a distribution but so does anything for which you want to compute a probability.

Comment: How can I define a distribution over $N^+$ then?

Comment: This comment is not meant to be not nice but...not knowing that a probability distribution is required seems that maybe this isn't a job for you.  But then again if the subject area is cryptography which I know nothing about, then maybe the standard assumption is a uniform distribution for any finite set of positive integers.

Comment: Could use `DiscreteUniformDistribution[{0,n-1]`

Comment: Are you looking to compute such a probability via simulation (e.g. actually computing a function on all naturals up to a certain point) or symbolically somehow?

Comment: I would prefer symbolically but will fallback to simulation if not possible.